# Get records between Two Dates with overlapping time intervals

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I have the following database

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`time` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`messages` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (1,1467311473,"Jim", "Jim wants a book"),
                      (2,1467226792,"Tyler", "Tyler wants a book"),
                      (3,1467336672,"Phil", "Phil wants a book");
```

I need to get the records between date 29 Jun 2016 and 1 July 2016 for time intervals 18:59:52 to 01:31:12. 
I wrote a query but it doesn't return the desired output

```
SELECT l.*
FROM table l
WHERE ((time >=1467226792) AND (CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(time/1000) as time) >= '18:59:52') AND (CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(time/1000) as time) <= '01:31:12') AND (time <=1467336672))
```

Any suggestions??

Comment: cast your timestamps to datetimes.

Comment: I'm really confused.  What is `'emd_date'` and `'start_date'`?  Why do you have string constants?  What columns are coming from the table?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the query doesnt work if start_date = 21:30:00  and end_date is 03:30:00

Comment: Store dates and times as a single entity

Comment: @Strawberry dates and times are stored as single entity but to get records between the given time interval needed to separate it

Comment: Why? That's very odd.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry have updated the question

Comment: Your table name keeps changing

Comment: @Strawberry apologies for the mistakes i forgot to update the query...here you go with the update

Comment: To be clear, 1.00 in the morning on the 29th should be exluded, right? And similarly 19.30 on the evening of the 1st?

Comment: @Strawberry yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you're simply interested in all periods greater than '2016-06-29 18:59:52' and less than '2016-07-01 01:31:12' where the time element is NOT between '01:31:12' and '18:59:52'

I think you can turn that logic into sql without further assistance

Ah, well, here's a fiddle - left out all the from_unixtime() stuff because it adds unnecessary complication to an understanding of the problem - but adapting this solution to your needs is literally just a case of preceding each instance of the column `time` with that function:

http://rextester.com/OOGWB23993

Comment: This would give the all the results between '2016-06-29 18:59:52' and '2016-07-01 01:31:12' ie also the results for 2016-06-30 for time greater than 01:31:12 and less than 18:59:52 which is not required. The time interval for all the days is from 18:59:52 to 01:31:12 and exclude all the others which doesn't come between these times

Answer (score 0):

If i got it right

```
SELECT l.*
FROM `table` l
WHERE  time >=1467226792
       AND time <=1467336672
       AND CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(time/1000) as time) >= '18:59:52' 
       AND FROM_UNIXTIME(time/1000) <= DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(time/1000) as date), INTERVAL 25 HOUR), INTERVAL 31 MINUTE), INTERVAL 12 SECOND)
```

Comment: The casting / "time/1000" stuff is surely unnecessary

Comment: Besides, this solution (if right) over complicates the problem